# Using @ag-grid-community/angular version <28 with Angular 16

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular-ivy

Did anyone figure out a way to use `@ag-grid-community/angular` version prior to `Ivy` support (<28) with Angular 16 ?
In Angular 16 they've removed the deprecated entry components and `ngcc`, so any version of ag-grid <28 breaks.

I've tried to monkey patch the `ag-grid-community/angular` package to remove the entry components reference, but it still breaks. Seems that it's happening because the package doesn't support Ivy. So I'm getting:

```
**Uncaught Error: Type AgGridModule does not have 'emod' property**
```

The easiest fix is clearly updating to ag-grid >=28, but currently, I am looking for all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Angular - AG Grid compatibility chart [AG Grid Version Compatibility](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/angular-compatibility/#ag-grid--angular-compatibility-chart),  Angular 16 needs at least AG Grid 28. So I guess it is better to upgrade.

Comment: And while you are updating the AG Grid 28,please do refer this link as well - https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/angular-compatibility/#migration-to-ag-grid-v28 . After I upgraded to 28 with Angular 14, all my components that had input parameters started throwing errors.  Once I removed the withComponents() for AGGrid Module from the app.module.ts file, it started working fine again.  Snip from the link above - "There are breaking changes, notably AgGridModule no longer supports .withComponents() as it is not required any more."